# How to move the KnpPaginator manual count to Repository class?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, knppaginator

I am using ***knppaginator*** to paginate a very large collection of entities, after not being happy with the performance I realized that they would fetch all the entities regardless of what page number was being passed, I inspected the query profiler and I never saw any offsets in the query. Anyway, this is what I found that works but I would like to move the part where I get the count and the entities back to the repository class, where I would like to use **createQueryBuilder** instead.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

    $page = $request->get('p', 1);

    $this->breadcrumbs(
        array(
            array('title'=>'Admin','path'=>'home'),
            array('title'=>'Customers','path'=>'customers'),
            array('title'=>'All'),
        )
    );

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $count = $em
        ->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(cb) FROM MWCoreBundle:ContactsBasics cb LEFT JOIN cb.login l LEFT JOIN cb.setting s')
        ->getSingleScalarResult()
    ;

    $entities = $em
        ->createQuery('SELECT cb,l,s FROM MWCoreBundle:ContactsBasics cb LEFT JOIN cb.login l LEFT JOIN cb.setting s ORDER BY cb.dateAdded DESC')
        ->setHint('knp_paginator.count', $count);


    $pagination = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($entities, $page, 50, array('distinct' => false));


    return $this->render('MWCoreBundle:ContactsBasics:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, any news on this one?

Answer (score 0):

no, knp paginator, run three query:

1. count items
2. get distinct ids by offset
3. get items by ids

count items:

```
SELECT 
  count(DISTINCT u0_.id) AS sclr_0 
FROM 
  users u0
```

get distinct ids by offset

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT u0_.id AS id_0 
FROM 
  users u0_ 
LIMIT 
  10 OFFSET 0
```

get items by ids:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
  users u0_ 
WHERE 
  u0_.id IN (?)
```